# Java: placing JButtons into a JFrame as a rectangle

Tags: java, jframe, jbutton

So I am doing a tic tac toe game for my school project and requirements are that the player can choose the width and height. So I started making this game with JButtons but my problem is how can I make it so that my buttons would construct a rectangle at the center of my frame based on the user's inputs. What would be the best approach to do this? I've gotten to the point where I add the correct amount of buttons to the frame but I have no idea what layout/layouts should I use to make the "gameboard" that is constructed from multiple JButtons appear as a rectangle to the center of the frame.

Comment: Please add more details/code about your problem and your own efforts/code this far to solve the problem so that people can help you better. Read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [GridLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html). See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html) for example.

Following are some other useful examples/links:

[javatpoint](https://www.javatpoint.com/GridLayout)

[tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/swing/swing_gridlayout.htm)

Comment: Thank you, i tried using GridLayout before but i didn't carefully read how it works. I got it working how i wanted!

Comment: I accepted it but i dont have enough reputation for upvote.

Comment: so, here is one upvote from my side ;)

Comment: ok... Acceptance is more important. It helps us to focus on other open questions.